# Basic KCL question

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I need to find the currents I1 and I2 in this circuit:
[image]

I apply KCL to node A to obtain:

\$5+1-I_1-I_2=0\$

or

\$I_1+I_2 = 6\$

However, I am stuck here. How do I solve this circuit?

Comment: Never mind node A. Look at the other two nodes in the circuit.

Comment: You have two variables and one equation. That isn't solvable without finding another equation. You always need at least 2 equations to calculate 2 variables. This has nothing to do with circuits - it's a math issue.

Answer (score 2):

One current supply cannot circulate current in the other mesh. There won't be any steady state electrical charge transfer between the meshes. Each meshes are independent circuits. The connection at point-A only keeps the meshes at the same potential; just like putting a common ground between two circuits.

There are two independent mesh current equations, each of them having only one unknown variable. Therefore, I<sub>1</sub>=1A and I<sub>2</sub>=5A.

Comment: @hacker804, FYI, what hk is describing is a result of the *cut-set* form of KCL. You can find more background about it [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee100/fa04/lecture_notes/EE100supplementary_notes_2_pp21to33.pdf).